# Why 2D array return 'null'?

Tags: java, android, arrays, multidimensional-array

i make a 2D String array in main activity but i make NEW in another activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
  public String[][] arr;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    requestpayment requestpayment=new requestpayment(getApplicationContext(), 1, 8, "boy");

    TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    textView.setText(arr[1][1].toString());
  }
}
```

---

In second Activity i use 2d array in this form :

```
int i=1;
MainActivity mainActivity=new MainActivity();

mainActivity.arr= new String[5][5];         
mainActivity.arr[i][0] = FLName;
mainActivity.arr[i][1] = Old;
mainActivity.arr[i][2] = Image;
mainActivity.arr[i][3] = Gender;
mainActivity.arr[i][4] = Description
```

to here و Everything work good and i can use array amount in **second activity**.

but when use 2d-array in **mainactivity** in this form :

```
 textView.setText(arr[1][1].toString());
```

return null :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.../....main.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

before , i make a **ArrayList** and New in another activity then i use in main activity and that work right , but for 2d array not work;

**Now , how i can use this array that maked new in another activity**

Comment: In the main class you are not initializing the array… and an arraylist() is different than an array.

Comment: you set i=0; at the beginning of your code and here arr[1][1].toString() (you call arr[i][1] where i=1 but you have not set the value for i=1)

Comment: @Alex , i=0 was a example - in fact i fill 2d-array via (for) Loop

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with `arr`? Couldn't `textView` be null?

Comment: @gMax , yes , i sure , i set "textView " with another amount and work right , but for array , NO!.

Comment: @Chloe33 , i know that array is not not initialized and an arraylist() is different than an array, but you mean that it's not possible use array that maked new in another activity(like arraylist())?

Comment: Who calls onCreate() and how? Have you tried printing the value of arr[1][1] using System.out.printin() in onCreate()?

Comment: Well in the main class you declare a variable String[][] arr. But when you go to use it in the main class it returns null, correct? Well where is that value coming from? If you called the textView.setText(arr[1][1].toString()); from the second activity it should work. But when you have the callback to the main class you are only referencing array that has not been initialized, how does the program know you are referencing the filled array from the second activity?  Because you are going from the main > second activity correct?

Comment: @Priyesh , 2D-arrat filled in another activity , in main-activity i need use value of arr[1][1],

Comment: @Chloe33 , i have a main-activity and a class - array declared in main-activity but initialized in another class - too ,i want use amount of array in main-acitivity

Comment: @Chloe33 , right , but befor i used this initializing form for a ArrayList<> and this work - but about array not work

Comment: Yes, well an array you have to explicitly declare… you can not dynamically add indexes. .. arraylist again. It is a primary difference between the two data types. and as Mentioned by myself and others, there is no communication back to the main class, how is the class to know which array you are trying to draw values from?

Comment: @Chloe33 , when i use this : " MainActivity mainActivity=new MainActivity(); ---&---mainActivity.arr= new String[5][5];   " mean that i'm trying to use a array that declared in another activity - right? - so , i make communication back between to class in this way - Not!?

Answer (score 0):

public String[][] arr was never initialized.

You need to do something like,

```
private String[][] arr = null;

public String[][] getArr()
{
    if(arr == null)
    {
        arr = new String[5][6];
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Although I personally think you probably wanted to make an array list, or maybe a List of String arrays.

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

If you wanted to send the array between activities, you should rather make a holder class that holds the array, make it parcellable, and send the holder between activities using Intent Extras. The http://www.parcelabler.com/ helps with making a class Parcelable.

Comment: i have a main-activity and a class - array declared in main-activity but initialized in another class - too ,i want use amount of array in main-acitivity –
     
 
- right , but before i used this initializing form for a ArrayList<> and this work - but about array not work –

Comment: You should post the other class too.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown enough code for me to say for sure, but that  `new` call makes it look like your second class is setting up the array on a different instance of your main class; you never show any communication between them.

Comment: i have a main-activity and a class - array declared in main-activity but initialized in another class - too ,i want use amount of array in main-acitivity - right , but before i used this initializing form for a ArrayList<> and this work - but about array not work –

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the `NullPointerException` should be related to the fact that you are referencing different *instances* of the `MainActivity`. Please have a look at the code below, which is working only when `arr` is declared static AND the array creation is happening before using it in the class where it is actually declared (and not created):

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SecondClass sc = new SecondClass();
    sc.printArray(1, 1);

    FirstClass fc = new FirstClass();
    fc.printArray(1, 1);
  }
}

class FirstClass {
  public static String[][] arr;

  public void printArray(int i, int j) {
    System.out.println(arr[i][j]);
  }
}

class SecondClass {
  SecondClass(){}

  public void printArray(int i, int j) {
    FirstClass fc = new FirstClass();
    fc.arr = new String[5][5];

    for (int x=0; x<5; x++)
      for (int y=0; y<5; y++)
        fc.arr[x][y] = Integer.toString(x*y);

    System.out.println(fc.arr[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay… To answer your question. MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity(); Only creates an object: Instantiates the object.  In the second class where you declare the String[][] you are assigning values and that is fine (although not a good design, unless a parent/child class relationship exists). If you were to call textView.setText(arr[1][1].toString()); in the second class you would have the values. But the thing is there is no call back. In other words your main class has no idea what the second class is doing.

I would look at other ways to persist your data. But if your do.  You need a way for the first class to know your added values to your array.  Which with out some sort of data persistence will be hard.

Why you are doing this in the first place is not clear. The problem is your design. Why are you going back and forth? There is no rhyme or reason.  Create your array in the class it will be used and if it will not be used in that class use a data store to persist that data (or pass the data to the next class via an intent; but only primitive types). There are a few ways to data persist in Android. Read the multiple tutorials out there.
Think of OOP principles. Only pass info if it is necessary.. Deal with the info in the class it is created (substantiated). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

// okay to return empty 2d array..
//simply create one function like below

```
public static int[][] subsets(int input[],int index) {
if(index==input.length)
{
    int arr[][]= {};
    return arr;
}
```